# what does elibc_FreeBSD mean in gentoo portage overlays?

Tags: freebsd, gentoo, glibc

I have a gentoo overlay which has been added to http://gpo.zugaina.org/. One of my ebuilds recMD5 now shows the use flag elibc_FreeBSD even though I didn't add it. I am also running into it for a [hadoop](http://gpo.zugaina.org/sys-cluster/apache-hadoop-common) package. It looks like all I need to do is add the use flag for the package but I would like to know what its purpose is.

I am also getting an error with

```
euse -E elibc_FreeBSD
```

ERROR: Use flag "elibc_FreeBSD" is masked and should not be added to make.conf.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait.  I knew the answer in 3 minutes but formatting and completeness are my downfall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Bit Of Background

Historically speaking some users of FreeBSD have not gotten along with users of the Linuxes.  For many years, until [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/), and it's children of whom Gentoo is one, users could not get true source code on their system, unless they chose to use the [FreeBSD Ports System](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html). For that reason FreeBSD users viewed themselves as superior, but as Gentoo and Portage matured, the stage was set for the battle pictured below(and the G is backwards, I know):

[image: Gentoo Vs FreeBSD]

Much like Portage uses the `ebuild` construct, ports [have the same rules](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/makefile-depend.html).  I linked dependency checking because that's the biggest one.  If you look at [Chapter 5, Section 5](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html), you can see that ports management could be considered by some anything from an annoyance to a headache.  As such the flag and project I explain below attempts to alleviate the issue by replacing the ports mechanism with portage. See **How The Flag Works** for more.

---

### Why Gentoo is Called a Meta Distribution

Please read [GLEP:22](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GLEP:22), part of the [**G**entoo **L**inux **E**nhancement **P**roject](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:GLEP), in which the Specification Section states:

> ### Keyword Fragments
>
> Each keyword needs to specify, either explicitly or
>   implicitly, the following parameters: ARCH, USERLAND, LIBC, and
>   KERNEL.
>
> **ARCH**
>   x86, amd64, cobalt, mips64, arm, hppa, ia64, ppc64, sparc
>
> **KERNEL**
>   linux, selinux, openbsd, freebsd, netbsd, macosx
>
> **USERLAND**
>   gnu, bsd
>
> **LIBC**
>   glibc, openbsd, freebsd, netbsd, macosx
>
> (The above examples are not meant to be complete. Hurd, for example is 
>   not included because I know very little about Hurd.)
>
> A fully-specified keyword would look like "ARCH-KERNEL-USERLAND-LIBC",
>   so, for example, "ppc-fbsd-gnu-glibc" would indicate a Gentoo system
>   corresponding to a ppc architecture running the FreeBSD kernel with a
>   GNU userland and glibc as the system C library.

`elibc` is short for Environment_LIBC which points to the **LIBC** keyword fragment.  **LIBC** is Linux's implementation of a C Standards Library.  Since the Standards Library is dependent upon all of the Keywords quoted above, it is set on system-wide basis, and through variable inheritance, a package basis in Gentoo (see `/etc/portage/make.profile` which is a symlink to `/usr/portage/profiles`, which is set using `eselect profiles`).

```
ecyoung@bedroom-gentoo ~ $ sudo emerge -av glibc
Password: 

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] sys-libs/glibc-2.20-r2:2.2::gentoo  USE="gd (multilib) -debug (-hardened) -nscd -profile (-selinux) -suid -systemtap -vanilla" 0 KiB

Total: 1 package (1 reinstall), Size of downloads: 0 KiB

Would you like to merge these packages? [Yes/No]
```

To produce the above **LIBC**, my profile contains or inherits:

1. **ARCH** - amd64
2. **KERNEL** - linux
3. **USERLAND** - gnu
4. **LIBC** - glibc

It's the keywording and enviroment variable USE Flags explained in this GLEP, that make Gentoo so powerful.  This system is the main reason I chose Gentoo as my primary distribution, and also the reason I will read and/or attempt to answer every question here tagged `/gentoo`.

Once the Keywords and Environment Variables are mixed with the per package USE Flags, the Meta Distribution is created.  While there isn't an infinite number of ways a package can be compiled, I can guarantee that every package on a Gentoo system has been affected by a USE Flag in one way or another.

---

### How The Flag Works

To install FreeBSD, you need to use the [Handbook provided by FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/index.html) to install FreeBSD, and then inside a fresh install use the [Gentoo FreeBSD instructions at the Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gentoo_FreeBSD).  Doing so adds the following functionality to FreeBSD:

> Gentoo/FreeBSD is a Gentoo system based on FreeBSD. It is FreeBSD with
>   the following changes:
>
> - Portage replaces ports.
> - The base system is managed by portage.
> - Software in ./contrib and ./crypto is replaced with Gentoo Linux
>     versions.
> - The rc system is replaced with OpenRC.
> - Python, wget and bash are included in the base system to support 
>     portage.
> - FreeBSD's bootloader is removed from the base system (useful for 
>     jails).

---

The maintainer of the two packages your question was concerned with has added the option to compile the package on a FreeBSD system.  If you aren't on a FreeBSD system then this change doesn't affect you.  **This was indicated by portage telling you that the flag was masked**. You don't need to change anything.  For a brief, and I do mean brief, explanation of the difference between FreeBSD and Linux, see [HTG Explains: What’s the Difference Between Linux and BSD?](http://www.howtogeek.com/190773/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-linux-and-bsd/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will probably have a follow up question on how to install the hadoop package on Gentoo (I'm working on a gentoo vagrant box) but that will have to wait until I'm done with work.

Comment: I have an answer for your hadoop question as soon  as you ask it...