# How do I emerge hadoop on gentoo?

Tags: gentoo

I'm attempting to emerge hadoop from the [ultrabug](http://gpo.zugaina.org/Overlays/ultrabug) overlay. But emerge is not able to find the packages.

```
layman -a ultrabug
emerge sys-cluster/apache-hadoop-bin
Calculating dependencies... done!

emerge: there are no ebuilds to satisfy "sys-cluster/apache-hadoop-bin".

emerge: searching for similar names...
emerge: Maybe you meant any of these: sys-cluster/pacemaker-gui, sys-cluster/ploop, sys-cluster/pacemaker?
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you run `layman -S`? after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I helped with the [question related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/what-does-elibc-freebsd-mean-in-gentoo-portage-overlays) to this one, I'd like to provide a bit of background here also.

### Background

You had listed the [Zuniga Overlay](http://gpo.zugaina.org/), hosted by Ycarus.  I looked up his user profile at the Gentoo Forums, and since the forum was created, he's only had 24 total posts.  When I first started using overlays the Zuniga/Ycarus Overlay was one of the first ones I added.  I found through experience though that the overlay upkeep was about as bad as his forum activity.  Ebuilds there quickly become stale or outdated.

---

### Good News

I do love the Search capability on the Zuniga site, so I use it to search for an ebuild.  Chances are that if a stale old version is returned as a search result on this site, someone somewhere has a newer version in an overlay that isn't Zuniga/YCarus, as you've already found out.

In case you didn't know, I wanted to show you, and the other readers here the *unofficial official* overlays that are somewhat supported and maintained by the Gentoo Developers.

1. Visit the [Overlay Projects Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Overlays/Dev_Guide)
2. Of Particular importance is [Section 5 - Giving Access To Your Overlay To Others](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Overlays/Dev_Guide#Giving_Access_To_Your_Overlay_To_Others), so please read it if you haven't already.
3. In that section is a brief description of `layman`, the tool Gentoo uses to add and manage overlays.

---

### What to do Now

Having completed the 3 Steps above, readers may be asking themselves why I'm going through all the trouble of writing this up.  **Here is why**!  You can find a list of all overlays, Developer maintained and otherwise, at the [official listing on the Gentoo GitWeb](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/).  This listing is an online Git repository separated by username (We called them overlays before git existed).  It's navigable, so if you find or need an ebuild after Googling the repository name, you can verify that it does truly exist in the overlay.

To search for an overlay using `layman`, the following one-liner will work (Using your example, which does contain what you're looking for, as I verified it this morning.  Both the bin and the core):

```
layman -L | grep ultrabug
```

To add the overlay:

```
layman -a ultrabug
```

Before an overlay can be used, it must be synced, as Mark pointed out, with:

```
layman -S ultrabug
```

Note that if you have more than one overlay, specifying nothing after the `-S` will sync them all

To remove the overlay, use (only do this when you no longer need the package):

```
layman -d ultrabug
```

These and other options can be found by using `man layman`

---

### Update

As per Comment, first we add the overlay:

```
$ sudo layman -a ultrabug
Password: 

 * Adding overlay,...
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman  && /usr/bin/git clone git://anongit.gentoo.org/dev/ultrabug.git /var/lib/layman/ultrabug )
Cloning into '/var/lib/layman/ultrabug'...
remote: Counting objects: 1897, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1150/1150), done.
remote: Total 1897 (delta 751), reused 1709 (delta 663)
Receiving objects: 100% (1897/1897), 421.45 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (751/751), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/ultrabug  && /usr/bin/git config user.name "layman" )
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/ultrabug  && /usr/bin/git config user.email "layman@localhost" )
 * Successfully added overlay(s) ultrabug.
```

Then we sync it with our others (Notice the last line):

```
$ sudo layman -S 

 * Fetching remote list,...
 * Remote list already up to date: http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/overlays/repositories.xml
 * Last-modified: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 18:20:37 GMT
 * Fetch Ok

 * Syncing selected overlays,...
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/ixit  && /usr/bin/git pull )
Already up-to-date.
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/java  && /usr/bin/git pull )
Already up-to-date.
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/mv  && /usr/bin/git pull )
Already up-to-date.
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/qt  && /usr/bin/git pull )
Already up-to-date.
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/sunrise  && /usr/bin/git pull )
Already up-to-date.
 * Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/ultrabug  && /usr/bin/git pull )
Already up-to-date.
 * 
 * Succeeded:
 * ------
 * Successfully synchronized overlay "ixit".
 * Successfully synchronized overlay "java".
 * Successfully synchronized overlay "mv".
 * Successfully synchronized overlay "qt".
 * Successfully synchronized overlay "sunrise".
 * Successfully synchronized overlay "ultrabug".
 *
```

Then we verify that it's seen by portage - Part A (I used `app-portage/eix` for this, but `emerge -s` will search.  See parsed database [6])

```
$ sudo eix-update
Reading Portage settings ..
Building database (/var/cache/eix/portage.eix) ..
[0] 'gentoo' /usr/portage/ (cache: metadata-md5-or-flat)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) Finished             
[1] 'ixit' /var/lib/layman/ixit (cache: parse|ebuild*#metadata-md5#metadata-assign#assign)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) Finished           
[2] 'qt' /var/lib/layman/qt (cache: parse|ebuild*#metadata-md5#metadata-assign#assign)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) Finished           
[3] 'sunrise' /var/lib/layman/sunrise (cache: parse|ebuild*#metadata-md5#metadata-assign#assign)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) Finished             
[4] 'mv' /var/lib/layman/mv (cache: parse|ebuild*#metadata-md5#metadata-assign#assign)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) Finished           
[5] 'java' /var/lib/layman/java (cache: parse|ebuild*#metadata-md5#metadata-assign#assign)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) Finished         
[6] 'ultrabug' /var/lib/layman/ultrabug (cache: parse|ebuild*#metadata-md5#metadata-assign#assign)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) Finished       
[7] '' /usr/local/portage (cache: parse|ebuild*#metadata-md5#metadata-assign#assign)
     Reading category 163|163 (100%) EMPTY!
Applying masks ..
Calculating hash tables ..
Writing database file /var/cache/eix/portage.eix ..
Database contains 19010 packages in 163 categories.
```

And lastly - Part B:

```
$ sudo eix hadoop
* sys-cluster/apache-hadoop-bin [1]
     Available versions:  ~1.0.3^m
     Homepage:            http://hadoop.apache.org/
     Description:         Software framework for data intensive distributed applications

* sys-cluster/apache-hadoop-common [1]
     Available versions:  ~1.1.1^mb ~1.1.1-r1^mb ~2.0.3^mb {ELIBC="FreeBSD"}
     Homepage:            http://hadoop.apache.org/
     Description:         Software framework for data intensive distributed applications

* sys-cluster/cloudera-hadoop [1]
     Available versions:  ~4.2.0^m {hdfs mapreduce}
     Homepage:            http://hadoop.apache.org
     Description:         Cloudera Distribution for Apache Hadoop

* sys-cluster/cloudera-hadoop-mr1 [1]
     Available versions:  ~4.2.0^m
     Homepage:            http://hadoop.apache.org
     Description:         Cloudera Distribution for Apache Hadoop MapReduce v1

[1] "ultrabug" /var/lib/layman/ultrabug
```

---

From investigation, it looks as if `sys-cluster/hadoop-common` is native to FreeBSD(from this post - and the one linked earlier), therefore, you must choose any of the other 3 depending on your requirements.  Also notice that as long as a package from an overlay is in use, **you should not delete the overlay**.

Comment: have you tried to install any of the packages? When I take these steps emerge cannot find them.

Comment: @JohnMercier See Update Section

Comment: eix-update is not picking up the ultrabug overlay. I can only see the message for portage. I tried layman -S and layman -s ultrabug. eix-update is still not working. I am trying this on my vagrant box moaxcp/gentoo64.

Comment: I just tried it on my laptop and I think I messed up the vagrant box with a little too much cleanup.

Comment: could removing /usr/portage cause eix to not find ultrabug? My cleanup script removes it before turning the vm into a box.

Comment: @JohnMercier Never Remove `/usr/portage`.  It contains the local copy of the Portage Tree after every `emerge --sync`.  Try the command `emerge-webrsync` to rebulid it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `eix-sync` after adding the overlay?
`eix-sync` is a shorthand for updating caches. Read [wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Eix#Method_2:_Using_eix-sync) for more details.