# Is there a way to run a Linux binary on macOS?

Tags: binary

Is there a way to run a Linux binary in macOS? I tried to run a binary but it said it isn't executable.

Comment: This will not work. The OSX kernel is somewhat different from a Linux kernel.

Comment: Well OS X does not use elf binaries, so it's a bit like trying to run windows .exe. However, a brief search finds this: http://www.osxbook.com/software/xbinary/
If you can recompile your code, it's not an issue.

Comment: XBinary requires a program that knows how to run your binary; it in and of itself doesn't run anything.

Comment: @ott-- You can use "wine" to run Windows binary on Linux. Maybe there is a wine-like thing to run Linux binary on macOS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These answers are half correct, because virtualization is a choice but there is another.  May I present...

### History

1. First there was [UNIX, circa 1972](http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html)
2. Then the Timeline Split

   - In 1977, for $90, [Bob Fabry and others](https://www.discoverbsd.com/2013/03/history-of-bsd-begginings.html), compiled/built the first versions of BSD, short for Berkeley Systems Distribution.
   - In 1991, [Linus Torvalds posted in a Newsgroup](http://www.livinginternet.com/i/iw_unix_gnulinux.htm), about software he used from Richard Stallman, who started GNU in 1983, and Linus'es UNIX was born.
   - Apple reacquired NeXT Software in 1996, after Steve Jobs was fired from Apple in 1984, and used the software and people there to build OS X.  OS X is the [Darwin OS](http://www.osnews.com/story/3757/Introduction_and_History_of_Darwin) + the NeXT Desktop Environment.  And now we're back to Bullet #1, as Darwin is a closed source fork of BSD.  For the Open Source Project, see [PureDarwin](http://www.puredarwin.org/).  For the Official Apple Developer Page, see [Apple Open Source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/).

---

### How We Can Use This

BSD's traditionally use the Ports system for Package Management.  The most widely used of these are the [FreeBSD Ports](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/).  Ports are packages installed directly from source.  Since the **same Linux applications come from the same sources**, you can run a Linux application if its port exists.  Don't use these Ports on a Mac because...

---

Since all of Apple's GUI's are written using the [Cocoa API - WikiEntry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)), [bundled with XCode - OS X for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/osx/), the Ports can be tuned to take advantage of this:

1. Install XCode for your version of OS X.
2. Bundled inside XCode is Apple's version of the GCC Compiler, and all the other associated tools.  To update the tools, see [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4).  The tools are OS Version dependant, ie **they are not backwards compatible**, to my knowledge (in short, don't install XCode for 10.8 on 10.6, etc.)
3. Having installed XCode you now have a compiler, and can head on over to the [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) page and browse for the port you need installed, after [installing the MacPorts .pkg installer](https://www.macports.org/install.php)

---

### Caveat

The ports system doesn't necessarily do dependency checking, unless the port was well written.  I lightly touched on the problem in [what does elibc_FreeBSD mean in gentoo portage overlays?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/what-does-elibc-freebsd-mean-in-gentoo-portage-overlays)

Answer (score 26):

**Update years later: The Noah repo has now been archived. I haven't found a good alternative.**

---

I recently starting using [Noah](https://github.com/linux-noah/noah) to run Linux binaries in macOS. You can install using homebrew (`brew install linux-noah/noah/noah`). Then you should be able to do this:

```
noah linux_binary
```

In my experience the behavior of the binary matches what I see on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: though the command worked and no errors did rise, my binaries did not work as expected

Comment: Outdated answer, it does not work anymore. `noah` has been removed from homebrew and the source code is archived.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know that this can be done via some sort of [virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization). For example, you could use [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) which is a wrapper of sorts around Oracle's VBox or VMware's vmplayer. The other thing that is sometimes done is put this in a container such as [docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Answer (score 2):

### Hardware Emulation

Not directly! Yes as rocky said, you have to virtualize it with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion), which will match your CPU type.

There's also [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), which will virtualize different CPU types i.e. Intel or Power etc.

### Software Emulation

There is also software layer emulation, with programs like [WiNE](https://www.winehq.org), and my own emulayer program(WiP) Both of these partially emulate the Windows OS by converting the system calls to POSIX.

Most Linux applications will run on OSX with a source recompile.