# SSH step in RelView 8.2 virtual-machine installation is failing

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install a Linux app called `RelView` on my Mac (running 10.12.5), or rather, the Arch Linux virtual machine version of it (see: [is there a way to run a linux binary on OS X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212754/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-linux-binary-on-os-x) for a different possible method). I'm using the latest version of VMware Fusion to run the VM.

Here is the developer's recipe for installation:
[image: Arch Linux virtual machine instructions]

Steps 1 through 6 were cake but 7 is a beast.  Since the VM defaults to a German keymap, my first problem was figuring out how to enter the symbol `@` from my US keyboard. The solution (found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console)) is to enter the command:

```
localectl set-[keymap] --no-convert [keymap]
```

(Note to developer: you might mention this in the instructions.)

Problem two was figuring out what IP address to enter from step 6.

Here is what happened when I tried entering every IP address in sight:

[image: screenshot of Arch Linux virtual machine]

Problem three is, if any of the above IP addresses were correct, none worked.

You see that steep rock face in the bottom right? It's emblematic of the difficulty of step 7 :(

I see there are other "SSH to virtual machine" posts already, but if anyone can at least point me in the right direction for taming step 7, it will help a lot.  Thanks.

========================

Joe's suggestion produced this result (using a different internet connection):

```
[rv@relview ~]$ ssh -X rv@192.168.254.14
The authenticity of host '192.168.254.14 (192.168.254.14)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:BgDdIcI8Y80 ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.254.14' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rv@192.168.254.14's password:
Last login: Mon Jun 5 02:11:42 2017
[rv@relview ~]$ relview

(relview-bin:399): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
[rv@relview ~]$
```

If there's an easy next step please let me know.

I don't absolutely have to use `RelView`, but at this point, just getting it to open has become an end in itself.

========================

Per Joe's second suggestion, doing step 7 in Terminal instead of from inside the VM produced the same result (my internet connection is now back to the original one):

```
Last login: Mon Jun  5 04:29:53 on console
Marks-MBP:~ mark$ ssh -X rv@192.168.43.52
The authenticity of host '192.168.43.52 (192.168.43.52)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:BgDdIcI8Y8O ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.43.52' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rv@192.168.43.52's password: 
Last login: Mon Jun  5 12:48:21 2017
[rv@relview ~]$ relview

(relview-bin:429): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
[rv@relview ~]$
```

Even though `RelView` still hasn't opened, maybe I at least understand better what's going on.  Apparently the purpose of the VM is to act as a server that my Macbook logs into to run the app.  The reason I didn't know this until now is because I've never installed an app this way.  (I was vaguely thinking the SSH step was to log into some central server over in Germany :)

Looks like my next task is to troubleshoot the Gtk-WARNING.

========================

Entering the command `echo $DISPLAY` in Terminal (both before and after running `ssh`) produced this result:

```
Last login: Mon Jun  5 05:48:46 on ttys000
Marks-MBP:~ mark$ echo $DISPLAY

Marks-MBP:~ mark$ ssh -X rv@192.168.43.52
rv@192.168.43.52's password: 
Last login: Mon Jun  5 12:49:45 2017 from 192.168.43.137
[rv@relview ~]$ relview

(relview-bin:491): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
[rv@relview ~]$ echo $DISPLAY

[rv@relview ~]$
```

I got the same result from the VM's command line too.

Comment: The IP4 address is 192.168.43.52 (/24 indicates the subnet size; .255 is a broadcast address). Does it mean that you should run `ssh -X rv@192.168.43.52` **from the host**?

Comment: Thanks for identifying what appears to be the correct IP address to enter.  But there are new issues (see my edit above).

Comment: Are you running `ssh` from within the virtual machine (`[rv@relview]` prompt suggests so)? Try running it from a command line in the host instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake.  Yes I was running `ssh` from within the VM.  Unfortunately the same warning comes up in Terminal (see my latest edit).

Comment: Hmm. What is `echo $DISPLAY`? In the host it should be something like `:0`, when you ssh into the guest it should be something like `localhost:10.0`. If it's blank, ssh X forwarding isn't working (and there are some things to investigate).

Comment: Everything comes up blank when I try `echo $DISPLAY` (result posted above).

Comment: Not a Mac expert. Search around on "ssh X forwarding on mac" - looks like you might need to add X11 support?

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for all your help Joe.  If I ever get this thing running I'll report back with the details.